# Error iterating a Multi Value Parameter in SSRS Custom Code

Tags: vb.net, loops, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have a Multi value parameter in SSRS 2016 populated by a dataset. I have set the parameter properties as follows Data type 'Date/time', 'Allow multiple values', visibility is Internal and I've pointed Available and Default values to my dataset which is a simple select query returning dates. Using a for loop in custom code, I want to check if a given date is equal to any of the dates in the parameter. Whenever I use the index in the For Loop to index the parameter value I get #Error however
when I hard code the index with a any number I get the desired result

```
While (dt < endDate)      
    For i As Integer = 0 To Report.Parameters!parameter.Count()
        If Report.Parameters!parameter.Value(i) = dt Then
            count = count +1
            Exit For
        End If                  
    Next i
    dt = dt.AddDays(1)
End While
```

I expect 1 to be added  count every time there's a match

Comment: If you have a Count of 1, it will run twice `i = (0 to 1)`. Maybe `To ....Count() - 1`

Comment: Thanks!!! Totally missed the fact that I was counting from index zero.